# Deployed Application runs on localhost but fails with a HostName/IP

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have deployed an ASP.NET (Webforms-C#) Application on IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012 R2). When I bind it to 80 port, it works fine as '\localhost\' but when I assign a HostName or IP address, I can no longer access the site. 'This Page cannot be displayed' error shows up when accessing the site.

I checked similar questions but they didn't help me with the issue.

Edit: Through IIS, when I 'Browse' my site, it works on localhost but not with HostName. I looked through similar questions and some suggestions were to check the Firewall, but I think Firewall comes second as that is for the remote access, right now my problem is that it can't even be viewed on it's own server where it's deployed.

Edit 2: It seems I can access the site remotely using the IP address of the server (it will use localhost) but still no luck with the HostName and user assigned IP.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:

1. **Bindings**
   Check your iis site bindings and if needed create additional binding with host name and ip address. if there are other sites then try a different port number [8080, or 8081 etc]
2. **Host file** Run notepad as an Admin then browse and open C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

*Create a new entry with as below with the following format*

```
"local ip/machine ip" Hostname
192.168.100.200 WINWEBDEV
```

*note: you may want to add this host entry on the host and machine you are trying to reach the site from*

3. Ports, Windows firewall, Antivirus, Event log,

*Or just open a browser press F12 on chrome or IE to see a bit more detail about the issue* Hope this helps